# handlebars.js helper doesnt work

Tags: javascript, helper, mustache

I am somewhat losing my mind here... I have the following code:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
  <div>{{post/name}}</div>
  {{#if post/attachments}}  
    <p>
    {{#list post/attachments}}<img src="{{url}}">{{/list}}  
    </p> 
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

And a helper which i copied directly from the each helper to make sure there were no errors.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(context, fn, inverse) {
  var ret = "";

  if(context && context.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
      ret = ret + fn(context[i]);
    }
  } else {
    ret = inverse(this);
  }
  return ret;
});

window.myTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#myTemplate').html());
window.myTemplate({post:{name:"Post!", attachments:[{url:"/images/preview.jpg"},{url:"/images/1.jpg"}]
```

This does not actually call the helper, code ends up looking like this:

```
<div></div>
<p>
  <img src>  
</p>
```

Now I do this with an each block and it works fine, what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was including handlebars.js more than once on my page, which was causing my helpers to be ignored.

Now, if only I could find a way to get those hours of my life back...

Comment: WOW! i was doing the same thing. apparently that is really easy to do!